# Why my function inside an addEventListener execute only a part of what is written?

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon,

I really hope someone can explain me...
I have a button addEventListener that calls 2 function inside.
It execute one function well, but the other function, it looks like it execute only part of it.
I can see that it adds correctly to the localStorage, but it doesn't change the innerHTML.
If i call the function outside of the addEventListener, it works perfectly to add to the localStorage and change the innerHTML.
Here are the functions:

This one works

```
function emptyEntriesBook(){
    titleBook.value = "";
    authorName.value = "";
    genre.value = "";
    textarea.value ="";
}
```

This one only add to the localStorage when inside the addEventListener, but makes everything when I call it alone outside of the addEventListener

```
function clickAddCount(){
    let nbBooks = localStorage.getItem("books");
    
    if (nbBooks != null ){
        nbBooks = parseInt(nbBooks)
        document.getElementById("countClick").innerHTML = nbBooks;
        if (nbBooks ==1){
            document.getElementById("bookChange").innerHTML = " book"
        } else{
            document.getElementById("bookChange").innerHTML = " books";
        } 
    }else {
        nbBooks =0
        localStorage.setItem("books", 0)
        if (nbBooks == 0){
            document.getElementById("bookChange").innerHTML = " book"
        }
        document.getElementById("countClick").innerHTML = nbBooks;
    } 
    nbBooks++;  
    localStorage.setItem("books", nbBooks)
}
```

```
function addFunctions(){
    clickAddCount();
    emptyEntriesBook();
}

addBook.addEventListener("click", addFunctions);
```

I am trying to build a app with Flask and Python

If you could explain me what is wrong... and how I should do, it would be great! Thanks

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I have one non related to this function, uncaught error sendButton is null, because i didn't enter the username

Comment: I tried this on my local machine, the functions are executing as per your logic. Nothing seems out of their way to me.

Comment: Oh... So it is a mystery.. or black magic! Is that possible that the problem is with my laptop or something like that? I find sometimes (often) when i try to change things, it has an lunatic erratic behavior, but as I am a beginner, I think of course it comes from me

Comment: By the way not related to this question why are you storing data in localstorage because if you want to store data then there is flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: It a project I have to make for the course i take to learn, and they ask to show the use of what we learnt in the course, so I try to work with the local storage and different keys. It is the final project and I struggle quite a lot..

Comment: I just saw something strange...(I changed nothing at the function) when i add a book, now, i can see that it add and change the innerHTML. But when i come back on the main page, it "removed" the innerHTML and come back to 0, even if there is something in the localStorage

Comment: So the solution I found is to use the function clickAddCount() only for the local Storage. And I created a new function outside of it to write the innerHTML i want..It seems that it works